# Estimation, Upper limits, Lower limits

Tags: estimation

Two rods of length 2.6 cm and 3.5 cm are measured correct to the nearest 0.2 cm.  The two rod are joined together, find the lower and upper limit of the new rod.

I get stuck.  HOw to do?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If the rods are correct to the nearest $0.2$ cm, then the first rod is in actuality somewhere between $2.4$ cm and $2.8$ cm. The second rod is actually somewhere between $3.3$ cm and $3.7$ cm. From this information, what do we know about the shortest the combined rod can be and the longest the combined rod can be?

Comment: The absolute error should be 0.2/2=0.1cm.  Therefore the length should be 2.6+-0.1 and 3.5+-0.1.   The trouble is after joining the rod...how to handle the joined port of the rod?